# "npm err: not a package" when installing node.js dependencies for Highstock-browserify

Tags: node.js, npm, highcharts, package.json

We've been using the same `package.json` for the past 5 months, and everything was working fined when we typed in `npm install`. However, when I try to `npm install` last Friday (September 25, 2015), I got [this error](https://gist.github.com/saiwaimaung/0955aa9d106d33dc8dc7) that caused by `highstock-browserify`. The log regarding of `highstock-browserify` from `npm-debug.log` is  [here](https://gist.github.com/saiwaimaung/0113870d0a1d4f290931) .

[Here](https://gist.github.com/saiwaimaung/57f97710c65efc42d077)  is the `package.json` which I validated online is a valid json with no syntax error.

I know it was caused by `highstock-browserify` because I tried to manually typed in `npm install` each dependencies, and I got the same error when I typed in `npm install highstock-browserify`.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/saiwaimaung/a6f87676560a5191eb71)  is the log from `/home/aeryon/tmp/npm-19221-LzKxpARy/1443452789166-0.7612447252031416/tmp.tgz`

The application is a `Flask Python` application.

Comment: Might be worth noting that `npm@1.3.10` is extremely old and no longer supported as of over a year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing this version solved the problem: `sudo npm install highstock-browserify@1.0.2`

Version `1.0.5` onward will cause the issue.